# how to click Elements javascript code in Webview android studio

Tags: java, android-studio, webview

```
<div><img class="_2snGchWsjFpMyNZLH-C5ri" src="https:cdn-gop.garenanow.com/gop/app/0000/100/067/icon.png" alt="Recharger Free Fire"></div>
```

how to click class class="**_2snGchWsjFpMyNZLH-C5ri**"

```
String className="_2snGchWsjFpMyNZLH-C5ri";
String javascriptCode = "document.getElementsByClassName('" + className + "')[0].click();";

webView.evaluateJavascript(javascriptCode, new ValueCallback<String>() {
      @Override
      public void onReceiveValue(String value) {
    
      }
});
```

Comment: What's the issue with your current code? And what is clicking on the img supposed to do?

Comment: My code is not working, I don't know why
In the normal case, when pressed, it moves to another page

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry bro for the delay
I want to create an android app that works on https://shop2game.com
He enters the user number, retrieves information, and charges gems in the Free Fire game